# HTTPNotFound error while running "terraspace up demo"

Tags: terraform, azure-rm, terraspace

I'm tring to create a demo environment with terraspace on Azure.
So I have installed and set up environment variable as it is descriped on [terraspace doc](https://terraspace.cloud/docs/learn/azure/). when I run "terraspace up demo" it creates resource group and then fails with bellow error. what would be the problem.

> Current directory: .terraspace-cache/eastus/dev/stacks/aks Creating
> Resource Group dev-eastus... Exception Armrest::Error:
> #Net::HTTPNotFound:0x00007f0e9b0f39c0 /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/armrest-0.1.3/lib/armrest/api/base.rb:43:in
> `request' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/armrest-0.1.3/lib/armrest/api/base.rb:18:in` block (2 levels) in class:Base'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/armrest-0.1.3/lib/armrest/services/storage_account.rb:12:in `check_name_availability' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace_plugin_azurerm-0.7.0/lib/terraspace_plugin_azurerm/interfaces/backend/storage_account.rb:17:in` exist?'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace_plugin_azurerm-0.7.0/lib/terraspace_plugin_azurerm/interfaces/backend/storage_account.rb:6:in
> `create' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace_plugin_azurerm-0.7.0/lib/terraspace_plugin_azurerm/interfaces/backend.rb:10:in` call'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/terraform/runner/backend.rb:25:in
> `create' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/terraform/runner.rb:51:in` block in terraform'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/hooks/builder.rb:25:in
> `run_hooks' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/hooks/concern.rb:6:in` run_hooks'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/terraform/runner.rb:50:in
> `terraform' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/terraform/runner.rb:15:in` block in run'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/terraform/runner.rb:97:in
> `time_took' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/terraform/runner.rb:14:in` run'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/init.rb:23:in
> `block in init' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/timeout.rb:107:in` block in timeout'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/timeout.rb:36:in
> `block in catch' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/timeout.rb:36:in` catch'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/timeout.rb:36:in
> `catch' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/timeout.rb:123:in` timeout'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/init.rb:22:in
> `init' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/init.rb:12:in` run'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/commander.rb:10:in
> `run' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/up.rb:49:in` apply'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/up.rb:26:in
> `perform' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/up.rb:11:in` run'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli.rb:236:in
> `up' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in` run'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
> `invoke_command' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in` dispatch'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/command.rb:76:in
> `dispatch' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in` start'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/lib/terraspace/cli/concern.rb:65:in
> `start' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/terraspace-2.2.6/exe/terraspace:7:in` <top (required)>'
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/terraspace:25:in `load' /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/terraspace:25:in` '

I tried different regions like uksouth and still I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the issue on two different contexts, here are the solutions that worked for me :

- Verification and correction of the config/terraform/backend.rb content, ensure every backend information is correct and refers to an existing backend
- Removal of backend.tf and provider.tf files in app/stacks/iac-xxxx directories, they were added by error and were causing conflicts with the config/terraform/backend.rb and config/terraform/provider.tf files

Hope this will help people coming to this thread like me